# Parameters of 'controller(_:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:)' have different optionality than expected

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

When I updated Xcode to 6.3 and Swift 1.2, this caused the function below to produce this ominous warning:

**Parameters of 'controller(_:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:)' have different optionality than expected by protocol 'NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate'**

Here is the function header:

> func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
>   didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath:
>   NSIndexPath!, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
>   newIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

When I follow what Xcode suggests, which is replace the ! with ?, the Xcode compiler rejects my lines that use the index paths, so I unwrap those values, leaving me with this:

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        switch type
        {
            case .Insert:
                if let newPath = newIndexPath
                {
                    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
                }
            case .Delete:
                if let path = indexPath
                {
                    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([path], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
                }
            default:
                break
            }
}
```

Now I have runtime errors that occur when inserting and removing rows using this method.  No error message or insight into what's going on.  Was this the correct way to address the warning message?

Comment: This warning still persists with xcode 6.3.1 update.  However I'm not having runtime issues any more because the error was later found in my custom cells